# Explain the android file and storage structure

Tags: android

I need an overview on how files are structured in android. 
I mean like in window, we have partitions that have folders and files, we have the system data on one of those partitions and so...
How is it for android ?, and what are the main directories I am dealing with ? Where is cache stored ? what do terms like internal and external storage mean ? and so...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html will get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can help to answer a small part of your question. 
It's recommended to check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) that clarify the data storage in android. 
But in a nutshell, four types of storage we have:

1) **App-specific storage**: Hthis classified to internal and external storage, each app has internal and external storage. internal storage cannot be accessible only through the application. which external storage can be accessible through other application, external storage in app specific storage can be found in path 
**data/data/[your package name]**

2) **Shared storage**: This storage which is like Gallery, Document, Pictures, etc.. . This storage can be shared through your applications.

3) **Preference**: SharedPreference is an application for Preference storage

4) **Database**: This type of storage where it's stored in databases, it usually private and cannot be accessible outside application.

I recommend if you need more details, read [file system in official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/FileSystem)

Comment: The articles provided in by CommonsWare up there are pretty good, better than the official docs